# Clean way to check if a LocalDateTime is in a given range (working hours of some business)

Tags: java, java-11, localdatetime

I need to check if a given LocalDateTime is during the opening hours of a business, which are

Monday - Friday, 8:00 - 12:30 and 14:00 - 18:00

Saturday, 8:00 - 14:00

I have the below method to do so, but I find it too cumbersome for such a simple requirement. Is there an eleganter way to make it cleaner and more readable? May be using some Java 8 lambda magic :-) ?

```
static boolean duringWorkingHours(LocalDateTime dateTime){
    //MO - FR 08:00 - 12:30
    //MO - FR 14:00 - 18:00
    //SA      08:00 - 14:00

    LocalDateTime morningStart   = dateTime.with(LocalTime.of(8,0));
    LocalDateTime morningEnd     = dateTime.with(LocalTime.of(12,30));
    LocalDateTime afternoonStart = dateTime.with(LocalTime.of(14,0));
    LocalDateTime afternoonEnd   = dateTime.with(LocalTime.of(18,0));

    LocalDateTime saturdayStart  = dateTime.with(LocalTime.of(8,0));
    LocalDateTime saturdayEnd    = dateTime.with(LocalTime.of(14,0));

    Set<DayOfWeek> weekDays      = Set.of(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, DayOfWeek.TUESDAY, DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY, DayOfWeek.THURSDAY,DayOfWeek.FRIDAY);

    boolean isWeekDay       = weekDays.contains(dateTime.getDayOfWeek());
    boolean isSaturday      = dateTime.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY;

    boolean isMorning       = (dateTime.isEqual(morningStart) || dateTime.isEqual(morningEnd))
            || (dateTime.isAfter(morningStart) && dateTime.isBefore(morningEnd));

    boolean isAfternoon     = (dateTime.isEqual(afternoonStart) || dateTime.isEqual(afternoonEnd))
            || (dateTime.isAfter(afternoonStart) && dateTime.isBefore(afternoonEnd));

    boolean isSaturdayRange = (dateTime.isEqual(saturdayStart) || dateTime.isEqual(saturdayEnd))
            || (dateTime.isAfter(saturdayStart) && dateTime.isBefore(saturdayEnd));

    return (isWeekDay && isMorning) || (isWeekDay && isAfternoon) || (isSaturday && isSaturdayRange);
}
```

Comment: Start by converting to LocalTime, and just compare to 8am etc.  No need to create the special LocalDateTimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a little helper to make the comparisons easier:

```
private static <C extends Comparable<? super C>> boolean isBetween(C value, C start, C end) {
    return value.compareTo(start) >= 0 && value.compareTo(end) < 0;
}

static boolean duringWorkingHours(LocalDateTime dateTime) {
    LocalTime time = dateTime.toLocalTime();

    switch (dateTime.getDayOfWeek()) {
        case SUNDAY:
            return false;
        case SATURDAY:
            return isBetween(time, LocalTime.parse("08:00"), LocalTime.parse("14:00"));
        default:
            return isBetween(time, LocalTime.parse("08:00"), LocalTime.parse("12:30"))
                || isBetween(time, LocalTime.parse("14:00"), LocalTime.parse("18:00"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Way more easier to read. Thank you very much.

Comment: You might want to keep the `LocalTime` objects for the boundaries in `static final` fields. Though I think that e.g. `LocalTime.of(12, 30)` is not much harder to read than `LocalTime.parse("12:30")` while saving the work of parsing a string…